# Pandas - Keep format as hours throughout column

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, formatting

I have a dataframe that has several "total hours" columns. My problem is when these accumulate over a 24 hours it starts formatting the data as `1900-XX-XX 00:00:00` to account for years, months, and days. I just want it to display total hours, even if it's in the thousands of hours. How can I do this? Below is a sample of the df currently where you can see line 5 has the issue:

```
    DATE        HOURS RUN               ACCUMULATED HOURS (PER JOB)     TOTAL ACCUMULATED HOURS
0   2019-11-19  04:30:00                04:30:00                        04:30:00
1   2019-11-20  04:00:00                08:30:00                        08:30:00
2   2019-11-21  05:00:00                05:00:00                        13:30:00
3   2019-11-22  03:00:00                03:00:00                        16:30:00
4   2019-11-19  1900-02-19 00:00:00     1900-02-19 03:00:00             1900-02-19 16:30:00
0   2019-11-13  01:15:00                01:15:00                        01:15:00
1   2019-11-14  01:40:00                02:55:00                        02:55:00
```

The expected output for line 5 is:

```
    DATE        HOURS RUN               ACCUMULATED HOURS (PER JOB)   TOTAL ACCUMULATED HOURS
4   2019-11-19  1200:00:00              1203:00:00                    1216:30:00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `pd.to_datetime()` to make sure everything is read as a datetime object and then you can use `.strftime()` within a lambda to get the desired format. In your case, it seems to be `"%H:%M:%S"` **EDIT** based on your edited expected output, we can simply add a condition in the lambda and force the "12" at the beginning, since as far as I know there's no datetime format the specifically matches your expected output:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = {'date':['2019-11-19','2019-11-20'],'hours run':['04:30:00','1900-02-19 02:30:00'],'acc hours':['04:30:00','1900-02-19 01:45:30']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['hours run'] = pd.to_datetime(df['hours run'])
df['acc hours'] = pd.to_datetime(df['acc hours'])
print(df)
cols = ['hours run','acc hours']
for i in cols:
    df[i] = df[i].apply(lambda x: str(((x - pd.to_datetime('1900-01-01')).days+1)*24+int(str(x.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))[0:2]))+str(x.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))[2:] if x.year < 2000 else x.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
print(df)
```

Original dataframe I'm working with (after applying `pd.to_datetime()`):

```
         date           hours run           acc hours
0  2019-11-19 2019-11-20 04:30:00 2019-11-20 04:30:00
1  2019-11-20 1900-02-19 02:30:00 1900-02-19 01:45:30
```

After applying the lambda:

```
         date   hours run   acc hours
0  2019-11-19    04:30:00    04:30:00
1  2019-11-20  1202:30:00  1201:45:30
```

Comment: I added the expected output to my question, I should have done this first for clarification, I'm sorry

Comment: Technically your code runs, but I'm confused as to the hard coding of `12`? What if the summed hours total anything but the twelve hundred range? For instance what about 900 hours? (the `HOURS RUN` would display `1900-02-06 12:00:00` for reference)

Comment: Oh, yes I misunderstood completely your expected output (I thought you specifically wanted the 12 to precede the hours) this shouldn't be hard to solve simply using .hour. I'll try to work it out in a bit (I'm about to head out for a 30 min drive)

Comment: Could you explain to me the reason of why 12 precedes the "%H:%M:%S" format? For instance 2 months and 19 days are 1896 hours, not 1200.

Comment: Yes I agree (well I actually get 1872 hours, for the year 1900) but I'm not sure, I'll need to look into this...the data is pulled from an excel spreadsheet where the column format is `[h]:mm`. The data was then entered by a user as `1200:00`, and although the cell contains `1200:00`, after clicking on the cell (and importing it to Pandas) the saved value is `2/19/1900 12:00:00 AM` for excel and `1900-02-19 00:00:00` for Pandas. I'm unsure at the moment why the math does not seem to add up

Comment: Hmm so I guess I'll wait until you get the expected output and edit my answer accordingly?

Comment: Ahhh, we were misunderstanding the format...what was originally posted is correct, as far as the sum of hours goes. `1900-2-19 00:00:00` is February 19th, with 0 additional hours. January has 31 days, so `(31 + 19) * 24 hours + 0 additional hours on the 19th = 1200 hours`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202745/discussion-between-ivan-libedinsky-and-55thswiss).

Answer (score 0):

My test data:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({"date": [2019-11-19","2019-11-20","2019-11-21"],"runs":["04:30:00","14:00:00","15:30:00"]})

date     runs
0 2019-11-19 04:30:00
1 2019-11-20 14:00:00
2 2019-11-21 15:30:00
```

I convert the hours into timedelta and apply cumsum() as demo:

```
def tdconv(td): 
     h,s= np.divmod(td.total_seconds(),3600) 
     m,s= np.divmod(s,60) 
     return f"{int(h)}:{int(m):02}:{int(s):02}"

df["cumsum"]=pd.to_timedelta(df.runs).cumsum().map(tdconv)

date     runs    cumsum
0 2019-11-19 04:30:00   4:30:00
1 2019-11-20 14:00:00  18:30:00
2 2019-11-21 15:30:00  34:00:00
```

Answer (score -1):

just do that below for your hour columns

```
columns = df.columns.values
for col in columns:
    df[col] = df[col].apply(lambda x : str(x)[-8 : ])
print df
```